# Select distinct shou

Tags: mysql, sql, select, casting, distinct

I'm stuck with this problem for days and still can't think of a solution.Maybe i'm just making it too complex.
So my query looks like this.

```
SELECT distinct Cast(Table1.Date as Date) AS 'Date', Concat(Round(SUM((ISNULL(Price.Morning,0) + ISNULL(Price.Day,0) + ISNULL(Price.Evening,0))*Tickets.Count),2),' €') AS 'Total' 
FROM Price,Tickets,Table1
WHERE Tickets.Price_ID = Price.Price_ID AND
Tickets.Table1_ID = Table1.Table1_ID
GROUP BY Date
;
```

The query should display distinct dates and total SUM should be displayed that was earned in the specific date.
[As you can see there still are matching dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KqKf.png)

EDIT. I don't know if i understood the criticism correctly but i applied these changes.

SELECT distinct Cast(Tabl1.Date as Date) AS 'Date', Concat(Round(SUM((ISNULL(Price.Morning,0) + ISNULL(Price.Day,0) + ISNULL(Price.Evening,0))*Tickets.Count),2),' €') AS 'Total' 
FROM Table1
JOIN Tickets ON Tickets.Table1_ID = Table1.Table1_ID
JOIN Price ON Tickets.Price_ID = Price.Price_ID 
GROUP BY Date
;

And i also understand that i need to provide more information for solution.
All the ..Concat(Round(SUM((ISNULL(Price.Morning,0) + ISNULL(Price.Day,0) + ISNULL(Price.Evening,0))*Tickets.Count),2),' €') AS 'Total' .. Is necessary because in the database there are Null values, thatš why there i use ISNULL function and 0 in case it is NULL because otherwise it brakes all the calculations.You can see that table here: [I edited the column names so you could see(table itself is in different language)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql7Zu.png)
(The column without name is not required for this)

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I guess Table1.Date is not a date field (otherwise why cast it) , your group by should also cast for consistency with your select and you don't need distinct with group by.And please get out of the habit of using implicit joins.

Comment: It's hard to see what's going on without having sight of your data (even if only a short example).
However, I would break it down using CTEs
First do your row sum up as a CTE, then use that dataset to do your GROUP BY, and finally worry about the formatting (adding the EURO sign).

Comment: @P.Salmon Table1.Date type is a Smalldatetime data type, but i have to format/convert it to date afterwards YY/MM and at last to only show YY.

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit join not coma separated old join method and use subquery for format of total . No need distinct

```
    select 'Date', concat(total,' €') from
   (
    SELECT  Cast(Table1.Date as Date) AS 'Date',  
    SUM(Price.Morning+Price.Day+Price.Evening) as total
    FROM Price join
    Tickets on Tickets.Price_ID = Price.Price_ID
    join Table1 on  Tickets.Table1_ID = Table1.Table1_ID    
    GROUP BY Date
    ) as t
```